# Make an image appear somewhere else to the image that is hovered over

Tags: html, css, image, hover

I need to make another image appear above the one I have now when it's hovered over.

This is what I have so far:

```
<p>
<a href="https://twitter.com/georgevere12">
<img    alt="Twitter Link" 
        src="images/buttons/./twitter.png"
        style="position:absolute; 
        top: 85%; 
        left: 11%; 
        width: 5.5%; 
        height: 10%; 
        border: none;"
        onmouseover="this.src='images/buttons/./twitter-hover.png';" 
        onmouseout="this.src='images/buttons/./twitter.png';" />
</a>
```

Which is changing the colour of the link like I want it to, but now I want another image to hover above it at the same time. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using css only. Use sprite image and position it.

**Demo**

```css
.twitter{
  display:block;
  border:1px solid red;
  width: 30px;
  height:30px;
  background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/qM7IYaM.png?1);
  background-position:-32px 31px;
  transition:1s;
}

.twitter:hover{
   background-position:-32px 63px;  
}
```

```html
<a href="https://twitter.com/georgevere12" class="twitter">
  
</a>
```

Comment: transition is an overkill I think.